# Bathtub Overflow gasket still leaking

Tags: leak, drain, bathtub, overflow

I had a leak a couple of days ago from the old bathtub overflow gasket which I then replaced with a brand new one. I have no idea since when it started leaking but good thing I caught it. The problem I have right now is that the new gasket doesn't seem to seal properly. I filled up the bathtub of water to make sure everything was all good but then I saw it was still leaking. Any idea?

[image: New Gasket Installed]
[image: Current Overflow Hole]
[image: New Gasket]

Comment: I put the flat part of the gasket against the flat part of the pvc. The side of the gasket you see on the image is against the bathtub behind it if that answers your question. I'll put it back and upload a new picture.

Comment: Yep, that sounds right. How's the fit? That cutout is a bit rough.

Comment: Indeed. The gasket is not fitting super smooth against the bathtub. I still have the hole in the ceiling from underneath and I when I look down I see a bit of light here and there. I was assuming that when I would put back the plate it would seal up everything but it doesn't look like it.

Comment: Have you tightened it as much as you dare? Are you using the correct screwdriver? (Those may be #3 Phillips.) Those washers tend to be squishy enough to accommodate rough fitment.

Comment: It was pretty tight but I'm sure it could be a tiny bit more.

Comment: Does your new gasket look the same as the old gasket?

Comment: You need to align the PVC to the hole in the tube,  The lip of the gasket should fit within the hole in the tub.  Have someone put down on the pipe to align the PVC within the hole.  When aligned, install the faceplate.  Check again from below and see if any light is coming through.  The chewed up lip on the gasket may indicate that it is not in the hole, but being pressed against the outside of the tub.

Comment: I've tightened the screws as much as I could and so far it's no longer leaking. I'll keep my ceiling open for a while just to make sure but it looks like the problem is solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see three potential problems.

1. The hole isn't very round, which would cause uneven compression of the gasket. You could Dremel out that hump at the top.
2. The pipe is misaligned. It seems to be sitting high, which would cause the gasket to be overly tight at the top and loose at the bottom. See if there's any way to adjust. Fixing #1 could help with this.
3. You're not tightening it enough. Soft rubber/neoprene gaskets can handle a lot of deformation, but it takes force.